# fine tune BERT in a small GPU

Tags: gpu, bert, finetuning

I want to to fine tune the BERT base model but the only accelerated HW I have access to is a couple of [Quadro 600](https://www.nvidia.com/object/product-quadro-600-us.html) GPUs which only pack 1GB RAM and 96 CUDA cores each.

My question: is it even possible to fine tune BERT over this HW? If so, would it be worth with so few CUDA cores available? How can I know whether GPU memory will fit all the data and parameters?

Comment: Nopes you can't fine-tune Bert with the above mentioned hardware (it depends on the seq length as well); better would be to extract the contextual embeddings and have something like Bi-Lstm maybe.